# Multiple forms in view and single submit in partial view

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

[image]

I have web page like this, *the red* section is a partial view includes actions for the forms which are in a tabbed form in the *blue section*. In fact, each tab is also a view, CustomerDef view calls them via [kendo ajax tabstrip tool](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/tabstrip/ajax) like this;

```
 @(Html.Kendo().TabStrip()
            .Name("tabstrip")
            .Animation(animation =>
            {
                animation.Enable(false);
            })
            .SelectedIndex(0)
            .Items(tabstrip =>
            { 
              tabstrip.Add().Text("Customer Info")
                    .LoadContentFrom(Url.Content("CustomerInfo"));
                tabstrip.Add().Text("Customer Address")
                    .LoadContentFrom(Url.Content("CustomerAddress"));
                tabstrip.Add().Text("Customer Payment")
                    .LoadContentFrom(Url.Content("CustomerPayment"));
                tabstrip.Add().Text("Identity")
                    .LoadContentFrom(Url.Content("Identity"));
              })
)
```

For the saving action, i have a generic javascript method **SaveRecord** in the root script file. And on the partial view, for onclick event, i have a method toolbarSaveAction. On each tab view, i call click event by placing the generic SaveRecord method.  Here what it looks like;

**PartialButtonView**

```
<input title="Save" type="button" value="Save" onclick="toolbarSaveAction();"  class="toolbarButton toolbarBtnMarginLeft" />
```

**Root.js**

```
function SaveRecord(action, controller, param, customData) {

    var form = $("[aria-expanded=true]").find("form");
    var validator = form.kendoValidator().data("kendoValidator");

    if (validator.validate()) {

        var data = form.serialize();

        $.ajax({
            url: '/' + controller + '/' + action,
            dataType: 'json',
            type: 'POST',
            data: data,
            success: function (response) {

                if (response !== null && !response.success) {

                    ..

                }
                else {
                         ..
                }

            },
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {

                ..

            }
        });
    }
}
```

**CustomerInfo View**

```
<script>
        function toolbarSaveAction() {
            SaveRecord('CustomerInfo', 'Customer', ['customerId']);
        }
</script>
```

**CustomerAddress View**

```
<script>
        function toolbarSaveAction() {
            SaveRecord('CustomerAddress', 'Customer', ['customerId']);
        }
</script>
```

And here is my problem, for each tab view, i have a toolbarSaveAction() method for save click event. When the first request of the CustomrDef page only the first tab is loaded so save action works properly, however if i click other tabs there will be multiple views loaded on the page and it means there will be multiple toolbarSaveAction(). So, when clicking the save action, how can i handle picking the right method?

Answer (score 1):

Hi maintain one hidden variable inside a dom then on kendo tab select assign the current tab text to that element

```
<input type="hidden" name="hdnSelectedTab" id="hdnSelectedTab"/>
```

then in javascript

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
                function onSelect(e) {
                   $('#hdnSelectedTab').val($(e.item).find("> .k-link").text());
                }
         });
```

Now for have only one action as toolbarSaveAction

```
<script>
    function toolbarSaveAction(selectedTab) {
        SaveRecord('CustomerInfo', 'Customer', ['customerId'],selectedTab);
    }
</script>
```

and pass the tab value from button as

```
<input title="Save" type="button" value="Save" onclick="toolbarSaveAction($('#hdnSelectedTab').val());"  class="toolbarButton toolbarBtnMarginLeft" />
```

and then finally in

```
function SaveRecord(action, controller, param, customData,selectedTab) {
   switch(selectedTab) {
     case "Customer-Info":
                  //    Implementation    
                   break;
     case "Identity":
                  //Implementation    
                   break;
     default:
            //default Implementation    
      }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but SaveRecord method should be generic, because there will be lots of forms in my project, a switch-case form is not suitable for this.

Comment: I guess then you should have the same switch case inside your toolbarSaveAction and SaveRecord can have generic implementations .